# What is the proper way to generate the series of week of the year within a date range using postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following query to get the weeks of the year within a date range which starts from a date in the past and ends in the current date:

```sql
select distinct(to_char(generate_series('2021-01-01', 
                                        current_date, 
                                        '1 day'::interval)::date, 
                        'IYYYIW')
       ) as year_week 
       order by 1;
```

I believe that it does the job, but I am not sure this is the best approach. Can anyone suggest a better or, for the sake of learning, alternative ways to do the same thing?

Note that I am using PostgreSQL.

**Update:** There are some requirements that may not have been very clear from the initial post above. I want the series to be generated for any date in any year. In other words, the result might span multiple years. Also, the week of the current date should be included in the result set too. Having said that you can try with the starting date being `2020-12-27` (27th Dec 2020) and end date being `2021-08-12` (12th Aug 2020). The result set should return as first week the `202052` and as last week the `202132`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible issues:

1. using SRF function (Set Returning Function) `generate_series` in expression list. It is better to use it in `FROM` clause.
2. `to_char` returns string, but returns string of numbers. If you really need just only week number, the [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function can be better.
3. You don't need to use `distinct` - just you can set increment to `7 days`. On small data the overhead is zero, but if we talk about ideal solution, then using `DISTINCT` clause is mistake.

Comment: With regards to `distinct`: The problem with `7 days` or `1 week` interval is that it does not necessarily count the week of the current_date. If the starting date is `Sunday` and the current date is `Thursday`, then the current week is not generated. With regards to `to_char` vs `extract`: I want the run this for a date range that might span different years. So, the the 32nd week of 2020 is different to the 32nd week of 2021. How can I use `extract` to get the `202032` and the `202132` in an integer format?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos if you need year too, then you need second EXTRACT function.

Comment: Why not just cast the `to_char` expression to integer?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm - to_char is relatively slow function, and you need to repeat slower conversion from strings to numbers. Sure, the good design depends on context. If I prefer performance for this case, then I probably write own function, that does this calculation directly. In this case, you need the week number across years, so the calculation based on epoch should be simple.

Comment: Surely so, `extract (year from d) * 100 + extract (week from d)` would be far more efficient. Need to make sure that `d` are Mondays so that it works correctly for weeks that span two years though.

Answer (score 1):

As per the points of @PavelStehule with "poetic" formatting:

```sql
select to_char(wd, 'YYYY-MM-DD": week "IW" of year "IYYY') 
from generate_series('2021-01-01', current_date, interval '1 week') wd;
```

| Result: |
| --- |
| 2021-01-01: week 53 of year 2020 |
| 2021-01-08: week 01 of year 2021 |
| 2021-01-15: week 02 of year 2021 |
| 2021-01-22: week 03 of year 2021 |
| 2021-01-29: week 04 of year 2021 |
| 2021-02-05: week 05 of year 2021 |

... and so on